# Why can't I render my depth map on a quad?

Tags: opengl, textures, framebuffer, depth-buffer

**Some intro:**

I'm currently trying to see how I can convert a depth map into a point cloud. In order to do this, I render a scene as usually and produce a depth map. From the depth map I try to recreate the scene as a point cloud from the given camera angle.

In order to do this I created a FBO so I can render my scene's depth map on a texture. The depth map is rendered on the texture successfully. I know it is done because I'm able to generate the point cloud from the depth texture using glGetTexImage and converting the data acquired.

**The problem:**

For presentation purposes, I want the depth map to be visible on a separate window. So, I just created a simple shader to draw the depth map texture on a quad. However, instead of the depth texture being drawn on the quad, the texture being drawn is the last that was bound using GlBindTexture. For example :

```
 glUseProgram(simpleTextureViewerProgram);
 glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,randomTexture);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
 glUniform1i(quadTextureSampler, 0);
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

The code above renders the "randomTexure" on the quad instead of the "depthTexture". As I said earlier, "depthTexture" is the one I use in glGetTexImage, so it does contain the depth map.

I may be wrong but if I had to make a guess then the last GlBindTexture command fails and the problem is that "depthTexture" is not an RGB texture but a depth component texture. Is this the reason? How can I draw my depth map on the quad then?

Comment: *"I want the depth map to be visible on a separate window"* - So you have 2 OpenGL windows and 2 [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context)? `depthTexture` i created in the 1st Context and should be displayed in the 2nd Context?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, I have two contexts. It is possible that I make the depthTexture on the first one. Let me check.

Comment: @Rabbid76 You are right. I render on the depth texture in my first context only.  I haven't used multiple contexts before so it is a bit confusing. In order to avoid problems, I just created every VAO and texture on both contexts. What is a simple way to now "update" the depth texture of the second context?

Comment: You don't need to update it. Just share the 1st context. Updating would mean reading the texture on the CPU and writing it into the texture in the 2nd context.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Is there a specific command for sharing? I had avoided sharing specifically because I couldn't find a good source to learn how to share. Also, I suppose sharing needs to happen before anything else or can I just do it after I create the depth texture in the first context?

Comment: Context sharing depends on the window framework. You have to specify the context which has to be shared when a new context (window) is created.